# Store and export data from C# application

Tags: c#, winforms

I'll try to explain this the best I can!

I've written a program that after some input, it brings 4 different text items into 4 separate ReadOnly text boxes. I'm looking to, when a user presses a button, it will store the strings from the 4 text boxes into a sort of table, so when the user then enters more data and it calculates a new set of 4 strings, when the press the button again, it will also store these values. The user should then be able to print this "table" style storage or export it into excel.

Comment: Any attempts to achieve desired behaviour you've described? What have you tried and where did you stuck?

Comment: I tried adding a DataTable and adding Columns however, as i am not familiar with this level of coding, I felt a bit out of my depth and this is probably overkill for the result I require. I need to store the 4 different string values in some format that it can be printed or exported. There will be numerous "rows" of information. For example, if talking in excel terms, there will be 4 columns, each time a user inputs his information, it returns information back in 4 separate text boxes. This information will then be returned, after the user presses a button, into a "Row".

Comment: I see nothing wrong in storing these 4 values in DataTable. If it's works for you - great, feel free to use it. There are also other ways to store these values (for example, you can use `List<Tuple<string, string, string, string>>`), all of them has its advantages and misadvantages, discussing about them looks slightly like offtopic here.

Comment: `DataTable` is ok to hold data and to visualize it. If you are not familiar with *that kind of coding*, then you have to read a book or find a tutorial to start at least understanding *that kind of coding*. Asking others to write a software for you is ... sigh.

Comment: What is your actual question? All that you've done is state the functionality that you want.

Comment: I am a novice at programming, and have committed myself to develop a program. I have it all working and finished except this issue which i am not familiar with DataTables. I think i could manage to get the first set of strings into the table, but I'm a bit stuck on how to then insert a new "row" to store the data values of the next set of strings.

Comment: I am struggling to explain in writing the issue now that I have read over it. My question is that for the results that i want, what is the best method i.e. DataTable, assigning these values to variables etc. Not for someone to write a whole code block for me. Once I have been pointed in the right direction, I will then go off and study the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be -

You can create a class with properties to hold all the text boxes values. Something like this -

```
    public class TextBoxesDetails
    {
        public string TextBox1Value { get; set; }
        public string TextBox2Value { get; set; }
        public string TextBox3Value { get; set; }
        public string TextBoxValue4 { get; set; }
    }
```

Next declare a global list variable of this type

```
List<TextBoxesDetails> TextBoxesDetails = new List<TextBoxesDetails>();
```

Now at the click of your button, store the values of all the text boxes into this list -

```
        TextBoxesDetails.Add(new TextBoxesDetails { 
            TextBox1 = TextBox1Value.Text ,
            TextBox2 = TextBox2Value.Text,
            TextBox3 = TextBox3Value.Text,
            TextBox4 = TextBox4Value.Text"
        });
```

Now just use this list to export to excel.

For exporting to excel, I would suggest, https://npoi.codeplex.com/. The tool is also available through Nuget packages.

Comment: Thanks Yogi. I will attempt this approach and research into this type of method for future references.

Comment: If all your needing is to be able to import to Excel, you would probably have an easier time just exporting a CSV file.